# Finding the SDE of $\int_{0}^{t} X_{s} ds$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Given a stochastic process $X_{t}$. Suppose we have the dynamic $dX_{t}=a(X_{t})dt+b(X_{t}) dW_{t}$. If I have $Y_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}X_{s} ds$, is it possible to find $dY_{t}$? What I want to express $dY_{t}=a(Y_{t})dt+b(Y_{t})dW^{1}_{t}$, I do not require that $W_{t}$ and $W_{t}^{1}$ to be the same, the can be different.

Comment: Taking integrals typically destroys the Markov property hence no, Y does not solve any SDE in general.

Comment: I agree with Did. Why do you want to express $dY_t$ in this way? What is your motivation?

Comment: I want to find $E[e^X_{t}]$ and $E[e^\int X_{s} ds]$ for some particular stochastic process. In some situation, the first one is computable. I am wondering if I can do for the second one as well.